# How to resize the width of cell in GridView in ControlsFx?

Tags: listview, gridview, javafx, cell, controlsfx

I'm using GridView to construct the view in my project. I'd like to use an item with a label and a image in GridView. But the image overlapped when I add at least two pictures.I don't know why? 
The cell Code follows :

```
public class AlbumCell extends GridCell<Album> {
ImageView img_cover;
Label ll_albumName;

@Override
protected void updateItem(Album item, boolean empty) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.updateItem(item, empty);
    // create the view;
    HBox box = new HBox();
    img_cover = new ImageView();

    ll_albumName = new Label();
    if (empty) {
        img_cover.setImage(new Image("Pic/bg.jpeg"));
        ll_albumName.setText("相册名");
    } else {
        img_cover = new ImageView(item.getCoverUrl());
        ll_albumName.setText(item.getAlbumName());
    }
    box.getChildren().addAll(img_cover, ll_albumName);

    setGraphic(box);
}
```

}

and I use GridView in fxml like this :

```
<StackPane   
      GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.columnSpan="3"
      GridPane.rowIndex="1" GridPane.rowSpan="5">
            <children>
                <!-- prefHeight="309.0" prefWidth="425.0" -->
                <GridView fx:id="albumsList" />

            </children>
</StackPane>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your images are all of the same size you could simply set cell width and height:

```
albumsList.cellWidthProperty().set(YOUR_IMAGE_WIDTH)
albumsList.cellHeightProperty().set(YOUR_IMAGE_HEIGHT)
```

where "albumsList" is of course the gridView (with the fx:id you specified).

If they are not all the same size I guess you will have to use the width of the largest and the height of the tallest

Comment: It does work but not perfect.When the size  is  smaller than the picture given, there still overlap.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand: do you know the size of all the images? If so you can use a size that is big enough to contain each one of them

Comment: Yes,but the size of it is limited. I think I can resize the image when it gei it . I will try it.